# Checking input values with array contents in C#.net

Tags: arrays, .net, if-statement

I have an array with 5 integer values.

I need to check each value in it against input values from a text box.

A label displays a `Value found` message if the input value exists in the array.
If not, the`Value not found` message is displayed.

How do I display the `Value not found` message correctly?

Here's my code,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int row;
        
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text);                

            for (row = 0; row < id.Length; row++)
            {
                if (id[row] == x)
                {
                    txtdesc.Text = "Value found!";
                }
            }

            txtdesc.Text = "Value not found!";
            
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like if the "Value found!" message has been put into `txtdesc.Text`, you wouldn't want to replace it with "Value not found!". So check the value of `txtdesc.Text` first, after the loop, before doing that.

Comment: Alternately, set a `bool` variable to false outside the loop, set it to true if the value is found, and use a ternary or `if`/`else` block to set the value of `txtdesc.Text` appropriately after the loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, but would't that display "Value not found" from the very first search even if the value exists in a later record?

Comment: What "later record" are you talking about? The code you've shown looks for a single value (from `txtid.Text`) in a single array (`id`). Also, I gave two alternatives, so you'll need to be more specific about what "that" means...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I'm sorry, but I can't quite figure out what you're suggesting to do. Can you please post an answer for me? Just so I can understand what I have to do, more clearly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going into great detail, using a flag is the simplest way of tracking a Boolean state when you are first starting out.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int row;
        
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text);                
            bool found = false;
            for (row = 0; row < id.Length; row++)
            {
                if (id[row] == x)
                {
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            txtdesc.Text = found ? "Value found!" : "Value not found!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

With LINQ, these things get a lot easier:

```
 // At the top of the file
 using System.Linq;

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try
        {
            int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text);                
            txtdesc.Text = id.Contains(x) ? "Value found!" : "Value not found!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I get it now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    try
    {
        int[] id = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int row;
    
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text);                

        for (row = 0; row < id.Length; row++)
        {
            if (id[row] == x)
            {
                txtdesc.Text = "Value found!";
        return; //only add this line
            }
        }

        txtdesc.Text = "Value not found!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize it could be this easy to fix, lol! Thank you so much!